# How can i setup this multi user PC?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-users

We are a 3D android game development team of three, and really low on budget. We have this computer now:  Intel core i5 6400 (4 cores), a GTX 970, and 16 gigs of ram. We have monitors of our own, and we want to make this PC multiuser.

For the OS what we will be using is Win 7, and each of us will have dedicated access to the computer. Each user will have a hard drive to use by himself, although an external hdd is used as shared cloud.

Now my questions are:

- how to set a different number of CPU cores to a user?
- how to set a different capacity of ram to a user?
- how can I keep the hard drives separate? (A users drives wont show up for the others)
- how to make every user have full access to GPU?

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you want to use it as a server which each of you connects to or do you want to have two mice, two keyboards and those two monitors connected and do independent work?

Comment: @Seth win 7, and i want 3 sets of mice, keyboards and monitors on it, so we can work independently.

Comment: And Intel core i5 6400 is not a [powerpc] (hint: read the tags description by hovering over it to see "32 and 64bit CPUs used in Macs from 1994 .. 2006. Also used in PlayStation3, many embedded systems, and some more esoteric *NIX boxes."

Comment: @Hennes sorry about the tags. I searched for multiuse, multi-user, and pc, the only thing i could find that was remotely related my question, was powerpc, and i don't have the privileges yet to make a new tag.

Comment: Note that there is a windows version designed for multiple separate users: Windows terminal server.  It is not cheap and you would also need two more PC to connect to it. Alternatively use a host OS and a hypervisor2 (example: vmware workstation) or a type-1 hypervisor. (e.g. vmware exsi). You would need windows licences for all three VMs. Which makes this neither cheap nor trivial to setup. Esp. in combination with possible android emulators, which I guess are VMs themselves.

Comment: @Hennes thanks. I will experimentally try this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is probably you won't be able to do that in a satisfactory way with the kind of tools you have at your hands. Every modern desktop OS is already a multi-user OS and usually shares the resources (RAM etc.) among all users. There's no distinct mapping of hardware resources to users.

With a standard OS (Linux, Windows) your best bet would probably to assign the processor affinity accordingly using the respective ways to do so (e.g Windows Task Manager, or `taskset` on Linux). This would probably have to be done for every process that starts so you're most likely better off just respecting each other.

Now the real problem you're facing is the actual management of inputs and possible concurrent user access.

Windows 7 doesn't support multiple, concurrent logged in users on a single physical computer and depending on your edition neither more than one via RDP (Remote Desktop). In addition (from what I know) Windows isn't able to give you separate desktops on a individual monitors. What you might be able to do is setup virtual machines and each of you might be able to use of those but there will be a performance impact and it will be quite noticeable and usually 3D won't work as expected.

You might be able to get something setup using Linux but it's an usual setup and (IMHO) more a like to what was done using mainframes. Wikipedia states on the [Multiseat Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration#GNU.2FLinux) entry that Linux does support such a scenario and even has some links on how to set it up. Maybe someone with some more Linux knowledge could comment on whenever it makes sense to run such a setup and what impact on 3D performance etc. you should expect?

From my experience android emulators are really taxing if it comes to hardware (haven't touched 3D) so having three people work on it using the hardware you got will probably not be a joy. Do you have some spare parts from other computers that you might use to build a second machine? Each of you got a display so there has to be some kind of hardware it belongs to? If that's the case it could be less time intensive and easier to get some cheap upgrades and if you use your personal phones for testing you could probably save on the graphics card.

Comment: Thanks. All our older computers are using the last era of nvidia graphic cards (gt 6600 and gt 9500), so its impossible to run unreal engine in fhd on them. I think my best bet would be switching to linux. Any good operating system for this case? (A linux distro that has the multiuser ability, and has 3D editing programs built for this)

Comment: You don't really need specialized 3D editing programs for that use-case as you're essentially (it seems) creating three independent graphical user interfaces that you're just outputting to different devices. The wiki article has some links to the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX). Those might get you started and well Ubuntu should be one of the easier systems to get started with. Mind you, I haven't tried or fully read the Ubuntu article!

Comment: actually, two users will work on 3D modelling, and one user will do coding and building. I might be able to run my windows programs through wine. I will deal with this issue later. I will use Ubuntu then. Thanks anyways, you helped a lot.

Comment: Certainly you need programs that do that but what I meant was that you don't need specialized programs to make them work with that multiseat setup (probably) so e.g. Blender should work fine and the IDE of your choice might already be cross platform as well (e.g. Eclipse/Android Studio).

Comment: Yes, it seems that software-wise i'm covered by ubuntu. I think I've gotten all the answers i needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a virtualized system but, like Seth suggested it won't be satisfactory and may require maintenance and 100% uptime is really doubtful, still if you want to go ahead go on reading

You would have already figured out you need multiple peripherals for each of your virtualized Workstation.
Which includes a mouse, keyboard, monitor etc. I'd suggest you to buy two more 'cheap' GPUs in addition to the 970, for your HOST OS and other two users, the user running off the first virtual machine gets the 970 for extra horsepower, in your case 3D rendering etc. Later two will run off the two additional GPUs. Host OS runs off the on-board CPU graphics. Sharing a single GPU in a virtualized environment is difficult. 
This is not a guide and by no means, I recommend you to follow this. 
This is just a hobby project that I tried and got it working.

Refer https://lime-technology.com/getting-started/ for a complete guide to setup a virtualized environment.

Before that just here's an outline of what you'll be doing

1.Download UNRAID for your setup, you can find it at lime-technology.com

2.Copy files to a thumb drive and run 'make-bootable' file. This will be your boot device

3.In the BIOS (if it sounds like a bio-fuel you should probably stop reading ahead), set all drives to AHCI mode and enable Virtualization support for CPU

4.Boot into the USB you created. Keep this system running and connected to the network

5.From another computer on this same network hit http://tower, you'll login onto your workstation. 
You have the option to purchase a key or try it for 60 days

Configure your system, CPU core, HDD, GPU, peripheral distribution among these machines.
Detailed info at lime-technology.com/videos/

If you can get it working that's it. It was a really amazing experience for me, got to learn a lot. If you'd like to see someone how used similar setup, check out www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuJYMCbIbPk

I personally won't recommend such a system because it's unreliable at times. I enjoyed building it more than using it

Good Luck !

Comment: I will definitely try it after my project is over, but for the time being,  i am low on time and resources, and as both of you said, its not ideal. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Yeah Good luck !

Comment: By the way, do you have any answer to my question in the above answer's comment?

Comment: Userful offers a commercially supported multiseat Linux solution called Userful Multiplier. It enables up to 10 users to simultaneously share one computer. It works with most graphics cards supported by X.Org/XFree86 as well as USB multiseat devices, has been tested on most major distributions, including Debian, Fedora, Mandriva Linux, SLED, SuSE and Ubuntu. A free two-user version of Userful Multiplier software for personal or trial use is available from their website.
(Source: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration#Requirements)
http://www.userful.com/userful-desktop-virtualization